# How to Make The Wheel Mesh Renderer At the Wheelcollider Position Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having a little trouble figuring out how to make the wheels mesh render er object match up with the Wheelcollider object. I have searched the internet and found a few brief answers for a different version of unity.

Here is my current code:

using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

```
public class Position : MonoBehaviour {

    public WheelCollider wc;
    public Transform tf;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        wc = GetComponent<WheelCollider> ();
        tf = GetComponent<Transform> ();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        transform.position = new Vector3 (tf.transform.position.x + (wc.suspensionDistance * 100), tf.transform.position.y);
```

I have know idea how to make this work please help!

Comment: This description is poor as hell. I've read through this a dozen times and I still have no idea what you're trying to do. What is the "visual non physical object - A model? A gameobject's position? Why does it need to match a factor of the wheel's suspension distance and not the radius? Why is the position offset being applied to an arbitrary Transform and not the wheel's Center property?

Comment: @HappyApple I will improve it sorry :)

Comment: @HappyApple have you ever used the wheel collider?  The position of the collider is moved arbitrary -- it does not update the transform of the object or the center of the collider.  It would be nice to be able to make the graphics of the wheel actually reflect the position of the collider. :-/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't believe you'll need to code this solution, with proper set up of components in the Hierarchy.[image: WheelCollider-MeshRenderer Hierarchy]

Let's say for example, your WheelCollider's radius is 1 (meaning the diameter is 2) in distance units, at a default Transform.Scale of 1,1,1.

Let's also say you have a 3d mesh of a wheel you wish to use. For example purposes we'll say you imported this model at a scale so that when placed in the scene with the default Transform.Scale of 1,1,1 - it occupies a radius of 0.5 distance units (meaning the diameter is 2).

In this scenario, you could simply have the WheelCollider on a gameobject **and make that object a parent** of another gameobject, which has attached the mesh. That child gameobject can have a Transform.scale of 2,2,2 and will visually match the Radius gizmo of the WheelCollider.

For your solution these numbers will be different. Decide the size of the WheelCollider's radius (visually) firstly in the scene, then parent it to your wheel mesh and apply the Transform.Scale **in that order.**

*Note that changing the WheelCollider's radius afterwards will NOT scale the child gameobjects.*

Comment: Thank Could you please attach a photo of the hierarchy i'm new to unity :)

Comment: Done, feel free to ask anything else

Comment: This does not appear to be correct.  The Y position of the wheel collider (and that of the children) is never changed.  The suspension causes the wheel collider to bounce around, but it's not reflected anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the OP's code, nor the accepted answer are correct.

The OP's code is bad because it puts the wheel at the wrong position (it's right sometimes, but usually wrong); and the accepted answer is wrong because it says you don't need code to achieve this.

Per the [Official Unity Tutorial for Wheel Colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/WheelColliderTutorial.html) you **need** to call `GetWorldPose` to acquire the pose of the wheel, and then you need to transfer that pose to the object which renders the wheel each frame.  (That means that the MeshRenderer and the Collider **do** need to be on different objects.) -- Hierarchy alone won't work, since the transform of the parent is not modified by the wheel collider (i.e. it will just stay at 0,0,0 forever even if the wheel is bouncing around and spinning, etc.)

Though, I do recommend the same hierarchy as proposed in the accepted answer, as it makes things easier to manage:

- Vehicle

  - WheelCollider1

    - WheelMeshRenderer1
  - WheelCollider2

    - WheelMeshRenderer2
  - etc...

Here's an example MonoBehavior script that will work if you attach it to each of the `WheelMeshRenderer#` objects (per the hierarchy above):

```
private WheelCollider wheelCollider;
private void Start()
{
    // Once, at startup, search up the tree for the nearest wheel collider,
    // and grab a reference to it.
    wheelCollider = GetComponentInParent<WheelCollider>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Each physics update, get the pose of the wheel in World space coordinates.
    wheelCollider.GetWorldPose(out var pos, out var rot);

    // Apply that pose to this object's transform.
    transform.position = pos;
    transform.rotation = rot;
}
```